# Ruby on Rails REST and SPA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm recreating my Node.js project using RoR just for study and stucked at very beginning. The app is a SPA so all I need is REST api.

Is there some way not to use `render` in every route like this?

```
render json: { admin: admin, result: result }
```

I'm not using `resources` tag, just single methods declared like

```
post 'api/login', to: 'login#auth'
```

Comment: how do you want to render instead?

Comment: Routes have absolutely nothing to do with rendering. There are several ways to DRY rails applications such as the responders gem and gems that handle JSON serialization such as JBuilder, ActiveModel::Serializers and fast_jsonapi.